# How to use Charset class and availableCharsets() method

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, iteration

This is my source:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    File file = null;
    Scanner scan = null;

    Charset cr = null;
    Map<String, Charset> map = null;
    try
    {
        file = new File("D:\\Tests\\New folder (2)\\doncho_encode.txt");

        map = cr.availableCharsets();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> encoding : map.entrySet())
        {
            String s = encoding.getKey();
            scan = new Scanner(file, s);

            // System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Try new encoding");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (scan != null)
        {
            scan.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I need to compare different charset value to

```
scan = new Scanner(file, s);
```

line and when it find correct to use it. In my example I catch "NoSuchElementException" in catch clause.

I understand, that method availableCharsets() returned to me SortedMap with all encodings, but why wen I compare keys to "scan" the exception is caught? How can look like correct iteration?

In my example text in file is with "UTF-16LE" encoding.

Comment: If your text file is in `UTF-16LE`, why are you iterating through the available charsets instead of using the correct one?

Comment: Because I've got program who need to check many files with undefined encoding.

Comment: Then that won't work at all. Find a library that is better at guessing encodings, and remember that it's still a guess. You can't necessarily know the actual encoding in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not an expert in using `java.util.Scanner`, but...)

When looking at [the Javadoc for the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) I can see that:

- the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) doesn't declare throwing `NoSuchElementException`
- but it's [the `nextLine` method which actually does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

So based on that, I guess your problem is not actually that the Scanner doesn't recognize a charset returned by `availableCharsets`. But actually the 
program fails to read the next (first) line from the file.

By the way - what I am saying and suggesting for you to focus is most likely better observable if you add `e.printStackTrace();` next to your `System.out.println("Try new encoding");`.

**TLDR**: I suspect the expection is thrown for a different reason than you think it is.